# Efficient conditional ceiling and floor in HLSL

Tags: math, floating-point, numbers, shader, hlsl

I was trying to figure this out for quite some time already, but I can't get it quite right. What I want to do is to round a `float` towards the nearest integer, based on a different `float`.

I basically need a function that should work like this:

```
float roundParam(float val, float dir)
{
    if (dir >= 0)
        return ceil(val);
    else
        return floor(val);
}
```

This is of course VERY inefficient, as it requires a branch per vector component. I figured this out, but it breaks for integers:

```
float roundParam(float val, float dir)
{
    return round(val + 0.5 * sign(dir));
}
```

Comment: Which is more important: efficiency  or correctness for all `float`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It needs to work for normal floats (numbers), but I don't care about NaN or Infinity.

Comment: Does it need to work when `dir == 0.0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @wim and his observation that `floor(x) = -ceil(-x)` and `ceil(x) = -floor(-x)` I was able to create this function that solved the problem:

```
float3 roundParam(float3 val, float3 dir)
{
    float3 dirSign = sign(dir);
    return dirSign * floor(dirSign * val) + dirSign;
}
```

Comment: The generates the wrong answer when the addition forms a rounded sum.

Comment: Don't you want `return dirSign * ceil(dirSign * val);` ?  Either way, this and the answer fail when `dir == 0`.

Comment: Actually I was thinking about `dirSign * floor(dirSign * val)`, but I thought that the `and`+2x`xor` were more efficient. Apparently that was not the case here. Nice that you could use the `ceil(x) = -floor(-x)` idea.

Comment: @wim GPUs are not good with operations on integers. Actually until up to a few years ago, they didn't support them at all. Their power comes from floating point operations. The "functions" `sign` and `floor` used above are actually highly optimized GPU intrinsics. They also support parallelization very well (can do hundreds or thousands of times of operations more at a time than CPUs). The drawback is that GPU threads work in so called 'warps' (or 'wavefronts', as AMD calls them) and all threads inside a give 'warp' must execute the same exact operations (so no dynamic branching).

Answer (score 1):

In C you can use the following well vectorizable function. Maybe you can use the same idea in `hlsl`. This solution is only suitable if you don't care about the difference between `+0` and `-0` (signed zero) for `dir`.

```
float roundParam_v2(float val, float dir)
{   
    union fl_i32{float f; int i;} x, y, d;
    x.f = val;
    d.f = dir;
    d.i = d.i & 0x80000000;   /* extract the sign bit              */
    x.i = x.i ^ d.i;          /* multiply x 1.0f if signbit is set */
    y.f = ceilf(x.f);         /* note that floor(z) = - ceil( -z)  */
    y.i = y.i ^ d.i;          /* multiply x 1.0f if signbit is set */
    return y.f;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are no `union`s in HLSL, though the same can be achieved with `asfloat` and `asint`. I ported your function and got
```float3 roundParam_v2(float3 val, float3 dir)
{
    float3 x, y, d;

    x = val;
    d = dir;
    d = asfloat(asint(d) & 0x80000000); /* extract the sign bit              */
    x = asfloat(asint(x) ^ asint(d));   /* multiply x 1.0f if signbit is set */
    y = ceil(x);                       /* note that floor(z) = - ceil( -z)  */
    y = asfloat(asint(y) ^ asint(d));   /* multiply x 1.0f if signbit is set */
    return y;
}```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't really do what I wanted. Thankfully though, I found a solution based on the observation that `floor(z) = - ceil( -z)` that I wrote using HLSL intrinsics.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
float roundParam(float val, float dir)
{
return ceil(val)*(float)(dir>=0)+floor(val)*(float)(dir<0);
}
```

It can be probably be further optimized, but that optimization is probably already made by the compiler.

Btw, if you add the `[flatten]` tag to the `if` conditional, it probably already gets optimized by the compiler. And for such a simple branch, it is most probably already flattened by the compiler whether you tag it or not.

It would be interesting to check the compiled code and see if the branch has already been removed. I’m currently afk so I cannot check...

Comment: Are the casts `(float)` needed?  Quiets a warning maybe?

Comment: I think they are not strictly needed, but as hlsl casts left to right, you might have big trouble if you don’t cast explicitly and invert the terms of the multiplication ( `(dir>=0)*(ceil(val))` returns a bool). I got the habit of explicit casting anywhere to avoid issues when I copy/paste parts of my code anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use an array of pointers selected by `dir`?

Below is C.  Unclear how usable such an approach is in `hsl, shader`

```
float roundParam(float val, float dir) {
  static float (*f[2])(float) = {ceilf, floorf};
  return f[!!signbit(dir)](val);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately in HLSL there are no pointers, no function pointers and most importantly no real functions (they are just syntactic sugar, that gets always inlined). That's a limitation of how the GPU works. In addition to that all threads executing in a local work group must execute the same instructions in order to achieve optimal performance (hence the problem in the first place).